# condition of tuple of integers

Tags: python, tuples, conditional-statements

how do I write a concise/neat boolean condition to test if all the integers in a tuple are in a given range? Something like

```
0 < (1,2,3) < 50
```

would be perfect - of course that doesn't work because it uses lexicographical ordering, so also

```
0 < (1,2,-3) < 50
```

evaluates to True. Instead I would want it to evaluate to True if and only if all the numbers are in the range.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
all(0 < n < 50 for n in thetuple)
```

should be a relatively concise solution. it may not be the shortest piece of code, but it is almost self-documenting.

Comment: And the inner parens are optional (I'd drop them).

Comment: Try `all(0 < n < 50 for n in (1,2,-3))` and see what happens . . .

Comment: @JoshAdel It returns False as expected no?

Comment: (I did check with Python 2.6 and Python 3.1 - I hope I'm not misreading the question, if so please point out what I got wrong)

Comment: What's supposed to - it returns False.

Comment: @Xavier and @Alexander: grrr. . . forgot I was working in pylab that does a `from pylab import *` call at startup and uses `numpy.all` instead of the python built-in.  Namespaces are a good idea. . .My apologies. . . You have my +1 now. . .

Comment: @JoshAdel: Namespaces are one honking great idea! ;-)

Comment: @Alexander: thanks, that's perfect and makes me learn a new python construct